# por que estos pedazos de codigo no funcionan cuando pongo or?

Tags: python, booleano

Hize un programa de piedra papel y tijeras.Todo me funciona bien(exepto cuando quiero agregar la opcion de 'tijera' o 'tijeras' como respuesta )quiero que me acepte las dos opciones como input.

```
#(esta es una version simplificada de mi codigo,para ahorrarles tiempo)
#1 == piedra, 2 == papel, 3==tijera    

pc_juega = 3

usuario_juega = 'tijera'


if pc_juega == 1 and usuario_juega.lower() == 'tijeras' or 'tijera':
  print('La computadora gana! roca le gana a las tijeras!! ')
elif pc_juega == 2 and usuario_juega.lower() == 'tijeras' or 'tijera':
  print('Tu ganas! la tijeras le ganan al papel!! ')
elif pc_juega == 3 and usuario_juega.lower() == 'tijeras' or 'tijera':
  print('empate con tijeras') 
else:
  print('movimiento invalido')

#output:

La computadora gana! roca le gana a las tijeras!!
```

(el output deberia de ser empate.)No quisiera quedarme con esa duda asi que estare muy agradecido de cualquier respuesta que me den.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresión:

```
if cadena == "esto" or "aquello":
```

no funciona como esperas. Es decir, no resulta en `True` cuando la cadena toma uno de esos dos valores. Por el contrario, es evaluada por Python como si hubieras escrito:

```
if (cadena == "esto") or "aquello":
```

Esta expresión es una composición booleana que resulta `True` si lo que hay a la izquierda del `or` es `True` (y en ese caso Python ni siquiera evalúa lo que hay a la derecha) o bien si lo que hay a la izquierda es `False` y lo que hay a la derecha es `True`.

En concreto. Si `cadena` tiene el valor `"esto"`, el lado izquierdo del `or` es `True` y por tanto toda la expresión resultaría ser `True`.

Pero si `cadena` vale por ejemplo `"xyzzy"`, entonces el lado izquierdo del `or` es `False`, por lo que python evaluará el lado derecho, para encontrarse la expresión `"aquello"`, que no es una expresión booleana, sino una cadena.

Cuando python encuentra una cadena donde esperaba una expresión booleana, considerará la cadena como `False` si es la cadena vacía (`""`) y `True` en cualquier otro caso. En este ejemplo, ya que `"aquello"` no es la cadena vacía, considera el lado derecho del `or` como `True`. Y por tanto toda la expresión es `True`.

En definitiva, esa expresión resulta ser siempre `True`, por lo que no funcionará como esperas.

Esta otra expresión sí que hace lo que pretendes:

```
if cadena == "esto" or cadena == "aquello":
```

También podrías cambiarlo por esta otra, más compacta (sobre todo cuando `cadena` es una expresión más larga, pues no necesitas repetirla):

```
if cadena in ["esto", "aquello"]:
```

en tu caso particular, ya que lo usas para admitir tanto "tijera" como "tijeras", aún tienes otra opción:

```
if usuario_juega.lower().startswith("tijera"):
```

aunque, claro, también admitiría cosas como "tijerapodo", etc.

#### Actualización

En realidad tu expresión es más compleja y tiene otro error:

```
if pc_juega == 1 and usuario_juega.lower() == 'tijeras' or 'tijera':
```

la expresión tiene tanto `and` como `or`. En la parte del `or` ocurre el problema que expliqué más arriba. Pero ¿qué pasa con el `and`? ¿Por qué entra por esta rama del `if` si `pc_juega` era 3?

Ocurre que el `and` tiene más precedencia que el `or`. Es decir, se evalúa primero. Para Python tu línea equivale a:

```
if (pc_juega == 1 and (usuario_juega.lower()=='tijeras') or 'tijera':
```

Comienza por mirar si `pc_juega==1` y sale que no. Por tanto todo lo que está entre paréntesis da como resultado `False`. Al hacer `or` de ese `False` con la cadena `'tijera'` el resultado es `True` por lo antes explicado (`'tijera'` no es una cadena vacía).

Deberías haber puesto paréntesis para forzar a que el `or` se evalúe primero. Esta sería la forma correcta:

```
if pc_juega==1 and (usuario_juega.lower()=="tijeras" 
                    or usuario_juega.lower() == "tijera"):
```

O más breve:

```
if pc_juega == 1 and usuario_juega.lower() in ["tijera", "tijeras"]:
```

Esta variante no requiere paréntesis porque `in` tiene más precedencia que `and`.